# In iOS through code I want to open iTunes and search a particular String passed through code

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)purchaseButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSString *iTunesLink =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms://itunes.com/%@",[self urlStringForSong:[songNameLabel text]]];
    iTunesLink=[iTunesLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}

-(NSString *)urlStringForSong:(NSString *)songName
{
    songName=[songName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    //remove mutilpe spaces by single space character
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"  +" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    songName=[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:songName options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [songName length]) withTemplate:@" "];

    NSCharacterSet *cs=[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM1234567890.-_* "] invertedSet];
    songName=[[songName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return songName;
}
```

Comment: what is the question? error message? expect output?

Comment: The code above is working fine for single word search(single word songName) but when i pass multiple words separated with spaces ,iTunes open saying item not found and on clicking the search button that is displayed below "Item not found"text it shows results as expected.

Comment: Can you please show the URL you are trying and is giving the error?

Comment: Url : itms://itunes.com/A%20New%20Irish%20Tune

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search for media you can take help from this 
[itunesLinkMaker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/)

```
hit this url with parameters you will get response json for searched results.
https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/wsSearch?term=**asd**&country=US&media=music&entity=song&limit=25&genreId=&version=2&output=json&callback=jQuery18302224650508724153_1404104878083&_=1404104902716
```

you can try [Itunes Search APi](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) this will guide you complete demo for searching from itunes.

Comment: The code above is working fine for single word search(single word songName) but when i pass multiple words separated with spaces ,iTunes open saying item not found and on clicking the search button that is displayed below "Item not found"text it shows results as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not escaping the spaces. You can't just put a space in a URL, it won't parse properly so you have to escape it using `%20`. the `%` escapes the character and `20` is the hexadecimal ASCII code for a space.

Replace this line:

```
songName=[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:songName options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [songName length]) withTemplate:@" "];
```

With:

```
songName=[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:songName options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [songName length]) withTemplate:@"%20"]; // Notice the %20 instead of a space
```

[See this link for more URL Escape Codes](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html)

Comment: I had tried this.But this too does not work.Any other suggestions would be appreciated.